# how to convert the num to date in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
date<-c(19970807,19970902,19971010,19970715)
df<-data.frame(id,date)
```

in which the type of the values in date column is 'num'. Now I need to convert the values in date column to 'date' type as 'yyyy-mm-dd'. I tried as.date after loading the 'zoo' library but it resulted in some unacceptable outcomes.
Would be thankful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you missed `as.character()`. In base R:

```
as.Date(as.character(date), format = "%Y%m%d")
[1] "1997-08-07" "1997-09-02" "1997-10-10" "1997-07-15"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(id, ymd(date))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to be complete, there was also a third possibility using `strptime`:

```
strptime(date,format="%Y%m%d")
[1] "1997-08-07" "1997-09-02" "1997-10-10" "1997-07-15"
```